# Rails 3 using OmniAuth Unknown Attribute Error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, omniauth, restful-authentication

I am trying to integrate OmniAuth to provide a self-contained way to authenticate users. So far, I am able to bring up the Login/Register dialog at the front of my app. However, when I try to register a new user, I get the following error:

---

```
ActiveRecord::UnknownAttributeError

Request

Parameters:

{"name"=>"jed",
 "email"=>"clampett@hillbilly.com",
 "password"=>"[FILTERED]",
 "password_confirmation"=>"[FILTERED]"}
```

---

I'm not sure where to even look for the problem. The addition of OmniAuth is following a tutorial in an O'Reilly book, Learning Rails 3. I have the following models pertaining to the authentication:

user.rb...

```
    class User < ActiveRecord::Base
      attr_accessible :name, :provider, :uid

      def User.create_with_omniauth(auth) 
        user = User.new()
        user.provider = auth["provider"]
        user.uid = auth["uid"]
        user.name = auth["info"]["name"]
        user.save
        return user
       end
    end
```

identity.rb...

```
    class Identity < ActiveRecord::Base
      attr_accessible :email, :name, :password_digest, :password, :password_confirmation
    end
```

I've added the omniauth.rb file to the "initializers" directory ...

```
    Rails.application.config.middleware.use OmniAuth::Builder do
      provider :identity
    end
```

I also created the sessions_controller....

```
    class SessionsController < ApplicationController
      def create
        auth = request.env["omniauth.auth"]
        if (User.find_by_provider_and_uid(auth["provider"], auth["uid"]))
        user = User.find_by_provider_and_uid(auth["provider"], auth["uid"])
        else 
          user = User.create_with_omniauth(auth)
        end
        session[:user_id] = user.id
        redirect_to root_url, :notice => "Welcome!"
      end

      def destroy
        session[:user_id] = nil
        redirect_to root_url, :notice => "Goodbye!"
      end
    end
```

Also, I added the following to my routes.rb file...

```
  match "/auth/:provider/callback" => "sessions#create"
  match "/signout" => "sessions#destroy", :as => :signout
```

Here is the schema...

```
ActiveRecord::Schema.define(:version => 20141116130255) do

  create_table "identities", :force => true do |t|
    t.string   "name"
    t.string   "email"
    t.string   "password_digest"
    t.datetime "created_at",      :null => false
    t.datetime "updated_at",      :null => false
  end

  create_table "todos", :force => true do |t|
    t.string   "task_name"
    t.date     "completion_date"
    t.boolean  "is_completed"
    t.datetime "created_at",      :null => false
    t.datetime "updated_at",      :null => false
  end

  create_table "users", :force => true do |t|
    t.string   "provider"
    t.string   "uid"
    t.string   "name"
    t.datetime "created_at", :null => false
    t.datetime "updated_at", :null => false
  end

end
```

The partial view for the authentication part:

```
<p>
    <% if current_user %>
        Welcome <%= current_user.name %>!
        | <%= link_to "Sign Out", signout_path %>
    <% else %>
        <%= link_to "Log in", "/auth/identity" %> |
        <%= link_to "Register", "/auth/identity/register" %>
    <% end %>
</p>
<hr />
```

It's a simple todo list app that I'm trying to add authentication to. Once I fix this error, I'm going to add a priveleges structure to it. 
What does this error mean and how do I fix it? BIG THANKS to anyone that can help point me in the right direction.

Comment: do you have all the fields in your db users table? if you've added all of these, did you run migrations?

Comment: so, you're having ActiveRecord error, so first of all I'd check your database schema. also you put Identity class here, but not using it... are you omit it's creation

Comment: Added the schema to the post above

Comment: can you also show the view?

Comment: The users table doesn't have password or password_confirmation. Should I migrate those fields to it? Or add accessors for them to the model?

Comment: @andreydeineko The authentication renders in a partial on top of the root page, I'm adding it to the post

Comment: http://railscasts.com/episodes/304-omniauth-identity take a look at this railscast episode

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to all who replied. Expecially Andrey - that railscast link really helped. I have solved the problem. Adding the missing password and password_confirmation fields to the identity model, but most importantly, I forgot that the the class itself is a class of Omniauth. Simply changed the model from:

```
    class Identity < ActiveRecord::Base
        attr_accessible :email, :name, :password_digest, :password, :password_confirmation
    end
```

To:

```
    class Identity < OmniAuth::Identity::Models::ActiveRecord
        attr_accessible :email, :name, :password_digest, :password, :password_confirmation
    end
```

Works perfectly now :) Thanks again to all!